# What method can I use to retrieve a string using two character indexes?

Tags: vb.net, string

Just like the title says; I want to use something like Mid(*stringName*, *startIndex*,[*integerLength*]), but instead of the third argument taking a string length, I want it to take the end character index. So in an example like *this*

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFG"
partial = *method I want to use*(alphabet, 2, 4) 'partial would equal "BC"
```

(Forgive me if my index numbers are off, but I hope you get my point.)

Does something like this exist in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use String.Substring

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx#Y0

```
dim alphabet as string = "ABCDEFG"
'partial is a reserved word!
'1,2 is the correct parameters to get 'BC'
dim partialString as string = alphabet.Substring(1, 2) 'partial would equal "BC"
```

Edit - Oooooh you want to do StartIndex,StopIndex not StartIndex,Length. Just apply a bit of math.

```
dim startIndex as integer = 1
dim stopIndex as integer = 3

'partial would equal "BC"
dim partialString as string = _
    alphabet.Substring(startIndex , stopIndex-startIndex )
```

I'd wrap that in an extension method on string, giving it a new name of course.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So from the answers I'm getting, I'm deducing there's no *built-in* method for this? Not that I can't do the math, just that, well... I'm lazy :)

Comment: @Quintis555: I wondered the same until I realized that you no longer have to figure out how to handle `3,2` when working with length.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Mid, the math for the length is quite easy (`length = endIndex - startIndex`):

```
part = Mid(alphabet, 2, 4-2)
```

You could also achieve the same thing with Substring (which uses 0 based indexes rather than 1 based):

```
part = alphabet.Substring(1, 3-1);
```

Comment: @Venk - No, it shouldn't. That's why yours is wrong. The second parameter to String.Substring is **length** not endIndex.

Answer (score -1):

```
targetstring=alphabet.Substring(2,4)
```

The above one should work..